# ASP.NET Core - How to send HTTPClient response to the client without reloading again

Tags: redirect, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-httpclient

I try to integrate a payment service into an ASP.NET Core 2.0 site. The payment page is called by sending a FORM via POST to the payment site which returns the payment page itself.,

My approach is to start the payment prcess by calling my WEB API. I build the form on the server and use HTTPClient.PostAsync to get the result from the service provider. Then I want the browser to display the payment page, but I cannot transfer the result from the PostAsync to the client along with it's URL, cookies, headers, etc.

Although I can redirect to the URL received in the HTTPRespnseMessage.RequestMessage.RequestUri, but the payment service blocks the transaction because of double access (first when I initially do it in the API call and second when the browser loads it again via redirect). The page correctly shown but with error message that the the transaction with same data cannot be restarted.

Is there any way to return the result of the POST to the client as if it were loaded from the browser? So that it displays the correct payment page URL in the address bar and the content I loaded in Content.ReadAsStringAsync().

Without redirect, the maximum what I can achieve now is to send the content to the browser but having my own WEB API URL in the address bar, which results in several problems like not found resource files, CSS and cookies, and all submits are faultily sent to my web server.

Thank you.